# Map JSON To List<Map<<String, Object>>

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper

I have a JSON of the format

```
[{
    "id" : "a01",
    "name" : "random1",
    "val" : "random2"

},
{
    "id" : "a03",
    "name" : "random3",
    "val" : "random4"
}]
```

I need to map it to a `List` holding various `Map` objects. How do I achieve it?

Even if I am able to convert this JSON to a `List` of `String` of the form

```
{
    "id" : "a01",
    "name" : "random1",
    "val" : "random2"

}
```

then I have a method to convert each individual `String` to a `Map`.

Comment: using jackson data-bind ? you can use guava to achieve it https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: Could you please guide me here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70907506/how-to-get-the-flux-response-into-map?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You will need to pass a `TypeReference` to `readValue` with the desired result type:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<Map<String, Object>> data = mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>(){});
```

Answer (score 3):

Use gson with specified type to convert to list of maps:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type resultType = new TypeToken<List<Map<String, Object>>>(){}.getType();
List<Map<String, Object>> result = gson.fromJson(json, resultType);
```

Answer (score 0):

**private List<Map<String, Object>> map_string;**

Json you need to pass:-

```
{
"map_formula" : [ 
        {
            "A+" : "if(price<400),\"40000\",0",
            "B" : "",
            "c" : "",
            "d" : "",
            "e" : ""
        }, 
        {
            "poor" : "value for poor",
            "good" : "300",
            "average" : "300",
            "excellent" : "300"
        }
    ]
}
```