# Map to a different type using ObjectMapper

Tags: java, rows, objectmapper

I have a piece of code.

I need to map `employeeRows` to `List<Map<String, Object>>` using `ObjectMapper` to pass it as an argument in `createResponse` method.

Could someone help me with this?

```
Publisher<employee> employeeRows = employeeService.list();

// Create response with our results
return createResponse(request, employeeRows, pivotValues);
```

Comment: Can you add more detailes , what is employee Rows and what is employee model ? maybe add an example ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to provide more details in your question, but I would try to make an reasonable assumptions and provide you with my best guess answer. First of all, why is in your code 
`Publisher<employee> employeeRows = employeeService.list();`
you invoke method called `list()` but it returns an instance of a class `Publisher<employee>` and not a list. Also if you try to serialize any instance of a class that is not a list into Json you will get a Json object (equivalent of a `Map<String, Object>` and not `List<Map<String, Object>>`). So, if you want to get a JSON list (equivalent of `List<Map<String, Object>>`) you have to have a `List<Employee>`. To do so is a strait forward task. You can use `ObjectMapper` class for it. But also I wrote am Open-source library that has a class `JsonUtils` which is a simple wrapper over `ObjectMapper` class that may simplify this task for you. Assuming you have a `List<Employee>` your code would look like this:

```
try {
  String jsonListString = writeObjectToJsonString(myEmployeeList);
} catch(JsonProcessingException jpe) {
  ...
}
```

Here is a Javadoc for [JsonUtils](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html) class. The library called MgntUtils and you can get it as [maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) or on [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including source code and Javadoc)

Comment: It is not a good idea to catch `Exception`. It is very easy to get an unexpected exception from a bug, then catch it and hide a problem. It is better to only catch a more specific expected exceptions.

Comment: @Lii This is just an example to demonstrate a code.  The method `writeObjectToJsonString` happens to throw `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException`. So for proper example I placed try - catch block there. But a user may catch any specific exception or not to catch it at all and have the method propogate it up. It is just an example

Comment: Catching `Exception` is such a common newbie mistake, so it is good to steer them away from that habit by never doing that in any examples! Just make up `SomeException` or similar instead!

Comment: @Lii, Pont taken. Answer modified

Answer (score 0):

I think that this question is similar to: [Map JSON To List<Map<<String, Object>>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698437/map-json-to-listmapstring-object)
As the answer states you can use TypeReference to achieve mapping into List<Map<String,Object>>

Comment: I don't think he is talking about json object, but anyway the question is too broad right now.